# Appium Calculator Program issue

Tags: android, automation, appium, mobile-application, appium-android

I am running Appium calculator first program but I am facing this error.
I have taken help from this YouTube link to just copy and run it by myself
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7vY3cPSo8g&list=PLhW3qG5bs-L8npSSZD6aWdYFQ96OEduhk&index=7

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 'app' option is required for reinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

`Original error: 'app' option is required for reinstall` means that you must specify `app` capability with an absolute path to your tested app:

```
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        ...
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "/path/to/your/application");
```